# Move Closed Software Recommendation Questions to Software Recommendations

Tags: discussion

Is there a standard practice for migrating recommendation questions? This closed question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165257/good-opensource-java-shopping-cart-frameworks-that-can-be-extended-to-use-lucene should be on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) because it has valuable information. The fact that it is closed but still visible on SO may encourage other users to post questions similar to it here.

Comment: Keep in mind that questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated. (Except by the devs, and that needs to be a _very_ special circumstance.) Also to note, since the question is already closed, users who see it should (if they're at all paying attention) notice this and realize that their question of the sort will likely _also_ be closed.

Comment: I'd be even less inclined to migrate old questions to Software Recommendations than to most other sites. Those kinds of questions seem particularly sensitive to the passage of time. Better to just ask a new question on SR and hope you get new and up-to-date answers.

Answer (score 11):

Software Recommendations has very [specific guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) about the questions it accepts, so migrating questions to the site is a rarity.  It's also not on the standard list of migration targets, but if you find good question that is on-topic for SR and off-topic for SO, you can use a custom 'other' flag and request a moderator to migrate it. They will review the flag and migrate it or not.

As far as [the specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165257/good-opensource-java-shopping-cart-frameworks-that-can-be-extended-to-use-lucene) you are referring to, it is from 2009 when these types of questions were considered on-topic for SO. It was closed years later because these are no longer on-topic here. The general rule thumb is we don't migrate questions that are older than 60 days unless there is some special circumstance for moving it.  I don't see any reason to migrate it now, so it will stay on SO closed as off-topic.

Comment: Interestingly, the 'specific question' that this question asked about is gone now. What happened to it? was it deleted? or migrated to Software Recommendations? or...?