# Consider migrating older, high-traffic/open software recommendation questions to softwarerecs.SX

Tags: discussion, migration, software-recs-se

Older questions requesting recommendations for pieces of software more naturally fit softwarerecs.SX these days. They would have been closed and then deleted had they been asked these days. Also, they typically (usually?) meet the softwarerecs.SX requirements, or are pretty close to meeting them.

So, why not migrate these questions to softwarerecs.SX?

Arguments which should be rejected against moving these questions:

- "Questions can only be migrated for 60/90 days after they are asked" - Heard this w.r.t. a specific question someone suggested moving (C++ IDE for Linux). That's not a serious objection, an exception can be made for when site devs do a mass migration to another site. It's sort of circular logic actually (won't migrate old questions since we don't migrate old questions).
- "Questions might not meet the softwarerecs.SX [guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314135/1593077)": Questions which have stayed open for a long while probably do, or at least - are close enough to meeting them so as to sort-of pass muster. Also, in case they don't - believe you me, they're still better than the vast majority of most questions people ask on softwarerecs.SX; and they can be made to meet the guidelines relatively easily by anyone who can edit.

The motivation for doing this is my (not-well-founded) impression that softwarerecs.SX is kind of struggling. The migration would:

- Bolster softwarerecs.SX with useful content
- Make people assume they should go there to look for recommendations rather than look on SX first

Comment: did you ask at [SR.SE meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) what they think about this?

Comment: @gnat - Nope but then if they did it would be a duplicate of [Questions already asked on Stack Overflow](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/106/questions-already-asked-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @gnat: Frankly, not yet; I had (perhaps incorrectly) assumed this was considered desirable. I will ask, later today or tomorrow.

Comment: voted down for ignoring what SR folks think about this

Answer (score 16):

We don't migrate questions that are over 89 days old because *everyone involved in that question has likely stopped caring about it.* No one is likely to be around to give clarification, the problem may not even be relevant today and any answers that the question received might look *really* out-of-place in 2016. There's no real benefit to shipping them over.

Now, that doesn't mean you can't draw some inspiration from them! If you find one and think *hey, I'd really like an answer to that!* - go ask it within the guidelines of Software Recommendations on the site. But please make sure it's something you're actually interested in and could benefit from, because you'll be lacking context to give clarification if necessary otherwise.

Comment: What if I qualified my suggestion to questions which have seen significant activity during the X days previous to the migration?

Comment: See question edit.

Comment: Does this also apply to highly voted questions about [project-management]? While it's probably true that nobody's maintaining the answers, many of these posts are about "soft" things, and thus are unlikely to be out of date.

Comment: Should "over 89 days" be "over 59 days"? Empirically, this is when the close dialog starts saying "too old to migrate".

Answer (score 10):

As a moderator on both sites: no. SR needs quality, not quantity - we already have plenty of quantity.

We can't migrate things that are older than 60 (90?) days, that's a limitation of the system. As Tim says, everyone has almost certainly stopped caring at that point. As far as I'm concerned, you're welcome to re-ask the question yourself on SR.

Also, I run across a lot of these old, still-open recommendation request questions. The vast majority of the don't pass SR's quality guidelines.

**That said**, I have no issues migrating questions that are within the migration window (definitely 60 days, maybe 90) and are high-quality enough. Flag it with an 'other' flag and we can move them.

Comment: It's not a limitation of the system, it just needs approval from higher up, that's all. And many of these are popular, relatively high-quality questions, with useful popular answers - and as poster children for that you can take, say, questions such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24109/1593077). Wouldn't you say SR has a "birthright" to that question?

Comment: @einpoklum If SR had been around when that question was asked, we could have migrated it then. That question has found a home on SO, with >650,000 views and a bunch of answers. I don't see any reason to migrate it now. It's off-topic here, yes, but our job isn't to find every question a home.

Answer (score 8):

I assume that most old, off topic questions are still open only because it isn't worth the moderation effort to close them all. You only get so many votes and flags to use a day and getting rid of new low quality questions is more important. It doesn't follow that an old, off topic question must be otherwise high quality if it escaped closure.

Furthermore, Software Recommendations has [already said no](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/questions-already-asked-on-stack-overflow) to this idea [twice](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/760/should-we-migrate-questions-from-other-se-sites).

Comment: See edit. Now I'm talking about either open or high-traffic question.